# Set of points covered by subspaces of small dimensions

Tags: co.combinatorics, discrete-geometry, affine-geometry, extreme-points

Let $S \subset \mathbb R^d$ be finite set of points. We say that $S$ is $2$-covered if $S$ lies in a union $V_1\cup V_2$ of affine subspaces such that $\dim(V_1)+\dim (V_2)\leq d-1$. For example, if $d=2$, a set is $2$-covered iff all or all but one point are collinear.

**Question**: Can we show that for each $d$, there is a constant $C$ such that if the size of $S$ is $n\geq C$, and each subset of $n-1$ points in $S$ is $2$-covered, then so is $S$?

For $d=2$, it is easy to show that $C=5$ works, and that is the smallest value (any $3$ points is $2$-covered, but $4$ points in general position is not $2$-covered).

Obviously, one can ask variants of this question about collection of subspaces with similar constraints, or finite fields, projective spaces, etc, so please share if you know some references.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. One can take $C=2d+2$.

I'll do the projective case, so my points will be nonzero points in a $d+1$-dimensional space $W$ and I'm looking for pairs of subspaces of total dimension $\leq d+1$ that cover them. My proof will work over any field, and probably for matroids too.

If $S$ is not $2$-covered, then clearly every set of $n$ points of $S$ spans $W$, as otherwise the space it spans and the line containing the missing point would give a $2$-covering. If this subset of $n-1$ points is $2$-covered, then since the two subspaces have total dimension $\leq d+1$ and together span $W$, they must be complements of each other.

If $S$ doesn't span $W$, then clearly it is $2$-covered. Let $v_1,\dots, v_{d+1}$ be elements of $S$ that form a basis of $W$ and let $w_1,\dots, w_{n-d-1}$ be the other elements. Form a graph with vertices $v_i, w_i$ and an edge connecting $w_i$ to $v_j$ if and only if $v_j$ appears in the expression of $w_i$ in the basis $v_1,\dots, v_{d+1}$. The graph must be connected, since a partition of the graph into two disconnected parts gives a 2-covering by the spaces spanned by the basis vectors in each part. However, removing any vertex $w_i$ must make it disconnected, since for a 2-covering, since the two subspaces are complementary, a vector in one subspace written as a combination of basis vectors must involve only basis vectors in that subspace.

Since every cycle involves a vector $w_i$, and removing a vertex in a cycle doesn't disconnect a graph, the assume the graph is a tree.

EDIT: this claim about graphs is not actually true, so the answer isn't currently correct.

Thus it contains exactly $n-1$ edges. But each $w_i$ has at least $2$ edges since it is not a basis vector (up to scaling), so the number of edges is at least $2 (n-d-1)$. Thus $n-1 \geq 2 (n-d-1)$ which gives $n \leq 2d+1$, contradicting $n\geq C=2d+2$.

This can probably be improved with a different idea...

Comment: For those who are trying to follow: the counter example to the current claim is something like two triangles ABC, ADE. Removing A will disconnect the graph. Of course, the graph Will is considering has much more structure, such as being bipartite (we can take ABCD, AEFG, still a counter example). So I am hopeful that this can be fixed soon, it is a very clever idea.